# My select menu shows each port (London, Liverpool, Dublin) each time for each record, I only want each port once

Tags: php, mysql

Here's the query, which is returning a search on my cruises and fares tables:

```
SELECT *, MIN(fares.offered) FROM cruises,fares 
WHERE cruises.departs > CURDATE() AND (cruises.destination LIKE %s OR 
  cruises.second_destination LIKE %s) AND 
  EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH from cruises.departs) LIKE %s 
  AND cruises.fromport LIKE %s 
  AND cruises.ship LIKE %s AND cruises.live = 'Y' 
  AND fares.cruise_id = cruises.id 
GROUP BY fares.cruise_id ORDER BY cruises.departs, cruises.fromport"
```

I have some jump menu's so that users can narrow the search, e.g the above query returns all cruises in July 2012, there are a few, some sailing from London, some from Liverpool.

My port select menu is populated with all the sailings, like this

```
London
Liverpool
London
London
Liverpool
```

Once for each returned record of sailings in July.

I only want

```
London
Liverpool
```

This is the select code:

```
<select name="jumpMenu3" id="jumpMenu3" onchange="MM_jumpMenu('parent',this,0)">
    <option value="">Select a port</option>
    <?php
    $port = ''; 
    mysql_data_seek($cruises, 0);
    while ($row_cruises = mysql_fetch_assoc($cruises)) { 
        if ($row_cruises['fromport'] != $port) {
            $port = $row_cruises['fromport'];
    ?>
    <option value="index.php?subj=2&destination=<?php 
       echo urlencode($row_cruises['destination']);
    ?>&departs=<?php 
      echo date('Ym',strtotime($row_cruises['departs']));
    ?>&port=<?php 
      echo urlencode($port);?>"<?php 
    if ($_GET['port'] == $row_cruises['fromport']) {
      echo "selected=\"selected\"";
    } 
    ?>><?php echo $port; ?></option>
    <?php } ;
    }
    if(mysql_num_rows($cruises) > 0) {
        mysql_data_seek($cruises, 0);
        $row_cruises = mysql_fetch_assoc($cruises);
    }
    ?>
    </select>
```

I thought about GROUP BY but I can't use that in my search query for the ports, because obviously there are more than one sailings from each port, maybe I need a separate query for the month select option - or can I group with php?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best approach would be another query just to retrieve the port names, like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT fromport FROM cruises WHERE cruises.departs > CURDATE()
```

You can add other conditions that should apply.

The second approach could be done within PHP:

```
$ports = array(); 
mysql_data_seek($cruises, 0);
while ($row_cruises = mysql_fetch_assoc($cruises)) { 
    if (!in_array($row_cruises['fromport'], $ports)) {
        $ports[] = $row_cruises['fromport'];
?>
<option value="index.php?subj=2&destination=<?php echo urlencode($row_cruises['destination']);?>&departs=<?php echo date('Ym',strtotime($row_cruises['departs']));?>&port=<?php echo urlencode($row_cruises['fromport']);?>"<?php if ($_GET['port'] == $row_cruises['fromport']) {echo "selected=\"selected\"";}?>><?php echo $row_cruises['fromport']; ?></option>
<?php
    }
}
if(mysql_num_rows($cruises) > 0) {
    mysql_data_seek($cruises, 0);
    $row_cruises = mysql_fetch_assoc($cruises);
}
```